# Expire Entry X days after status changed to X

Tags: channel-entries, date, expire

I would like an entry to fall off of a Channel Entries loop when X days have passed since the status was changed to X. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Or even another method?

I could have them just set the expiration date out X days instead of using the status change method, I was just looking for an easy and intuitive way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

I thinks is no such function from the box.  You can make ext. I [made small example](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx_status_change) for you. This ext. don't have any ui for settings, so you will need to setup what you want in

```
if ($meta['status'] != $status_prev && $meta['status'] == "closed" ) 
{

    $this->EE->api_channel_entries->meta['expiration_date'] = $this->EE->localize->now + 30*60*60*24; // 30 days +
}
```

Comment: Nice presentation of add-on :-) How could i hook auto_expire onto mx_notify? Auto_expire does an update on exp_channel_titles where entry_date > 30 days but i would like to mx_notify the authors their entry has expired....

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Max! I'll play around!

Answer (score 1):

I use auto_expire for this. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/auto-expire

> ... automatically expire new entries. It adds a predefined amount of time to the entry date

auto_expire just runs an SQL query on entry_date > offset change status.

p.s. +1 for swift max_lazar on status change add-on, set expiration_date on status change.

Comment: I looked into auto-expire but I need it to auto-expire when status is changed to X not when an entry is created. I was also hoping it would have the ability to take a date field and define X time and have the add-on automatically set the expiration date to X time after the date in date field.

Comment: This plugin is no longer supported in EE2.8 and up. Anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: @DimitriKouvdis Where did you get info that auto_expire is not compatible anymore with 2.8+ ? Should be somewhat easy to fix probably, source: https://github.com/AboutWout/auto_expire.ee2_addon

Comment: Sorry, please ignore. It seems to be working now. Lots of people having issues in the Support forums on devotee.

Comment: My one problem with auto_expire is that you can't send a reminder to the author when the entry expires (or flush caches). For that i (am going to) use 'Scheduled Trigger'